# Eigenvectors computed by Matlab's princomp() and eig() have different signs

Tags: pca, matlab

I am trying to write a PCA function in MATLAB. I know that there is the function `princomp`, I just wanted to understand the process for myself. One problem I've encountered is that the `eig` matrix calculation on the covariance matrix is incorrect. I have this covariance matrix:

```
matCov =

0.6166    0.6154
0.6154    0.7166
```

And when I call the *eig* function, I get:

```
eVec =

-0.7352    0.6779
 0.6779    0.7352
```

Whereas, with the function *princomp* I get:

```
eVec =

-0.7352    -0.6779
 0.6779    -0.7352
```

I know that it's the same, but each time I calculate the eigenvectors matrix (ordered by decreasing variance values) using the `princomp` function and the `eig`function, the last column of the eigVectors matrix are different. Can anyone explain this?

Comment: The sign of the principal component / eigenvector does not matter, it is arbitrary. There is nothing "false" in your example. Pca() and eig() functions uses different algorithms, so no wonder that they converge to solutions that can differ in sign.